# How can I accept the 'Paid Apps' agreement in AppStoreConnect for iOS app subscriptions?

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-developer

Can anyone help me? I'd like to create subscriptions in my iOS app and I need accept "Paid Apps" agreement in AppStoreConnect, but I have only "Free Apps" active agreement and can't find for paid.

I checked all Apple Developer account and AppStoreConnect and still can't find it

Comment: Were you able to make this show up? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Same situation... did you manage with it?